# Why input value can not be changed when pressing escape

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, reset

I have an input (outside form) that captures name of an image. User should fill in a new name and hit enter. Ajax callback renames the image. This works.

I'd like to add ability to 'reset' the input content when the user presses escape (#27). But I'm not able to fill the value of the input with my value.

The code is

```
<input id="escapeInput" value="this is test" /> <input type="button" id="setDetaultToEscapeInput" value="Set default" />

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#escapeInput").keydown(function(evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
            var input = jQuery(this);
            input.val('some default value') // doesn't work
            input[0].value = 'some default value 2'; // doesn't work
            input.parent().append('changed');
        }
    });
    jQuery("#setDetaultToEscapeInput").click(function() {
        var input = jQuery("#escapeInput");
        input.val('some default value') // works ok
    });
});
```

The interesting thing is that if I test e.g. for 'A' character ( if (evt.keyCode == 65)), the code works.
Any idea how to handle it? It doesn't work only in FF (Opera and IE8 are OK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the keyup event instead.

```
$(function() {
    $("#escapeInput").keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            $(this).val("some default value");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#escapeInput").keypress(function (evt) {
        var keycode = null;
        if (evt.keyCode) {
            keycode = evt.keyCode;
        } else {
            keycode = evt.which;
        }
        if (keycode == 27) {
            $(this).val("some default value");
        }
    });
});
```